# Angular ng-if with ng-repeat throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Howdie do,

So all I'm trying to do is display a set of options depending on a scope variable.

The weird part is that for some reason, even when the condition fails, the ng-repeat is still running.

The scope variable that is being switched on is $scope.code

```
<select id="customer-dd" ng-model="selectedCustomer">
     <option value="">select...</option>
     <option ng-if="code == 'multiAdmin' || code == 'admin' " ng-repeat="companyCode in companyGroups"  value="{{ companyCode }} " >{{ companyCode }}</option>
     <option ng-if="code != 'multiAdmin' || code != 'admin' " ng-repeat="company in code" value="{{ company }} " >{{ company }}</option>
</select>
```

This is causing the following error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: company in code, Duplicate key: string:m, Duplicate value: m
```

So, for example, the $scope.code = 'multiAdmin', the first ng-repeat should execute which it does.

But the next ng-repeat shouldn't execute as the condition code != 'multiAdmin' || code != 'admin'

But for some reason, based off the error, the next loop is executing and loops through the code which has two 'i' in it and causing the error.

So my question is, how do I ensure that the second ng-if/ng-repeat combo doesn't execute when the code == 'multiadmin' or 'admin'

*** Update ***

It seems that ng-repeat executes regardless of the conditional. It just doesn't display the results based off the conditional.

Comment: Fix your conditions to do what you need to do. Judging by your explanation, the second should be `ng-if="!(code == 'multiAdmin' || code == 'admin') "` instead of the one you are using.

Comment: This actually did it for me. I'm not sure what's different between the conditional I wrote vs the one you've provided, but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track by something them, for example by `$index`:

```
<select id="customer-dd" ng-model="selectedCustomer">
     <option value="">select...</option>
     <option ng-if="code == 'multiAdmin' || code == 'admin' " ng-repeat="companyCode in companyGroups track by $index"  value="{{ companyCode }} " >{{ companyCode }}</option>
     <option ng-if="code != 'multiAdmin' || code != 'admin' " ng-repeat="company in code track by $index" value="{{ company }} " >{{ company }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you @Michelem for your reply and while yes, this does get rid of the error, it doesn't address the problem of the second ng-if/ng-repeeat not executing. The code == 'multiadmin' so only the first loop should execute and not the second. That's all I'm attempting to accomplish.

Comment: It seems that ng-repeat executes regardless of the conditional. It just doesn't display the results. So your answer actually is the fix

Answer (score 0):

You wrote wrong condition expression in the second `ng-if`.

> ensure that the second ng-if/ng-repeat combo doesn't execute when the code == 'multiadmin' or 'admin'

So the second `ng-if` should be:

```
 <option ng-if="code != 'multiAdmin' && code != 'admin' " ng-repeat="company in code" value="{{ company }} " >{{ company }}</option>
```